# Unexpected overwriting of "unique_ptr" in vector

Tags: vector, unique-ptr

I recently learnt about the usage of `unique_ptr`, hoping that I can get rid of the copying overhead inherent from the store-by-value nature of STL containers. However I encountered a really strange behavior and couldn't figure out why.

```
struct LargeObj
{
    int id;
    LargeObj(int _id) : id(_id)
    {
        cout << "[" << this << "] is constructed\n";
    }
    ~LargeObj()
    {
        cout << "[" << this << "] is destroyed\n";
    }
    // Simulate huge data size
    int data[10000];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<unique_ptr<LargeObj>> store_by_pointer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        LargeObj obj(i);
        store_by_pointer.push_back(unique_ptr<LargeObj>(&obj));
    }
    for (auto ite = store_by_pointer.begin(); ite != store_by_pointer.end(); ite++)
    {
        printf("ID: %d\n", (*ite)->id);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows

```
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
[00000000001A6180] is constructed
[00000000001A6180] is destroyed
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
```

My question is why does each `push_back` replace all the items in front of it and thus make all the objects the same as the last one being pushed, which in this case is the `LargeObj` with ID 9.

Answer (score 0):

You should construct `unique_ptr` from the pointer returned by `new`, not the address of a stack variable - or even better, use `make_unique`.  You should also make sure to use `std::cout` consistently or `printf` consistently.  Try again with:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct LargeObj
{
    int id;
    LargeObj(int _id) : id(_id)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << this << "] is constructed\n";
    }
    ~LargeObj()
    {
        std::cout << "[" << this << "] is destroyed\n";
    }
    // Simulate huge data size
    int data[10000];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<LargeObj>> store_by_pointer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        store_by_pointer.push_back(std::make_unique<LargeObj>(i));
    }
    for (const auto& ptr : store_by_pointer)
    {
        std::cout << "ID: " << ptr->id << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your problem was that there only was one `LargeObj` (on the stack).  Every time round the loop the same piece of memory was constructed on the stack as the `LargeObj`, and at the end of the loop, the `LargeObj` was destroyed (the destructor called).  After the loop, you printed out the contents of a (non-)random bit of stack; strictly speaking, this is undefined behaviour, and *anything* can happen.  However printing out the value of the last ID you had stored is a not particularly surprising result.

On predicting what undefined behaviour will do:  This is a useful thing to do when debugging (so you can understand the behaviour of your code), but it is *extremely* dangerous to write the code to rely on it.  It will change - in the most bizarre and unhelpful ways imaginable.

Also note that I have included the headers, so this becomes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://MCVE) (and used `std::` and use the iterating for loop.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer and the correction of my grammar.